# In Racket, can I export functions after another function has been called?

Tags: c, scheme, racket, ffi

I'm trying to create a binding to libpython using scheme's FFI.  To do this, I have to get the location of python, create the `ffi-lib`, and then create functions from it.  So for instance I could do this:

```
(module pyscheme scheme
  (require foreign)
  (unsafe!)

  (define (link-python [lib "/usr/lib/libpython2.6.so"])
    (ffi-lib lib))
```

This is all well and good, but I can't think of a way to export functions.  For instance, I could do something like this:

```
(define Py_Initialize (get-ffi-obj "Py_Initialize" libpython (_fun -> _void)))
```

...but then I'd have to store a reference to libpython (created by link-python) globally somehow.  Is there any way to export these functions once link-python is called?  In other words, I'd like someone using the module to be able to do this:

```
(require pyscheme)
(link-python)
(Py_Initialize)
```

...or this:

```
(require pyscheme)
(link-python "/weird/location/for/libpython.so")
(Py_Initialize)
```

...but have this give an error:

```
(require pyscheme)
(Py_Initialize)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do something like this is to delay the binding until they're needed.  Something like this (untested) code:

```
#lang scheme

(require scheme/foreign)
(unsafe!)

(define libpython #f)

(define (link-python [lib "/usr/lib/libpython2.6.so"])
  (if libpython
    (error "Foo!")
    (begin (set! libpython (ffi-lib lib))
           (set! Py_Initialize
                 (get-ffi-obj "Py_Initialize" libpython
                              (_fun -> _void))))))

(define (Py_Initialize . args)
  (error 'Py_Initialize "python not linked yet"))
```

Ir you can do the setting inside the function itself, so you don't bind functions that are never called:

```
#lang scheme

(require scheme/foreign)
(unsafe!)

(define libpython #f)

(define (link-python [lib "/usr/lib/libpython2.6.so"])
  (if libpython (error "Foo!") (set! libpython (ffi-lib lib))))

(define (Py_Initialize . args)
  (if libpython
    (begin (set! Py_Initialize
                 (get-ffi-obj "Py_Initialize" libpython
                              (_fun -> _void)))
           (apply Py_Initialize args))
    (error 'Py_Initialize "python not linked yet")))
```

and since you won't want to do this for every single function, you should wrap it in a macro:

```
#lang scheme

(require scheme/foreign)
(unsafe!)

(define libpython #f)

(define (link-python [lib "/usr/lib/libpython2.6.so"])
  (if libpython (error "Foo!") (set! libpython (ffi-lib lib))))

(define-syntax-rule (defpython <name> type)
  (define (<name> . args)
    (if libpython
      (begin (set! <name> (get-ffi-obj '<name> libpython <type>))
             (apply <name> args))
      (error '<name> "python not linked yet"))))

(defpython Py_Initialize (_fun -> _void))
(defpython Py_Foo (_fun _int _int -> _whatever))
...more...
```

But two highlevel notes:

- Even though it's possible, it seems ugly to delay things this way.  I'd rather use some environment variable that is known when the code starts.
- There have been an attempt in the past to link [plt scheme to python](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/scheme/pubs/scheme2003-ms.pdf), and IIRC, dealing with memory issues was not pleasant.  (But this is before we had the current foreign system in place.)

Comment: Two things:  1.  This is going to be a library.  I'd prefer to leave configuration up to the application developer.  2.  I didn't realize this had been attempted in the past.  To be honest, I jut thought it would be an interesting project to work on while I'm doing benchmarks.

Comment: As it turns out, the previous approach was a bit different.  They wrote a Python-to-Scheme compiler.  It looks like as of that paper, they hadn't done anything with Python's C API.

Comment: I'm don't remember what was actually described in the paper, but I know that Daniel tried several approaches, and one of them involved dealing directly with the Python C level.  IIRC, the fundamental differences in approaches (is Python doing only reference counting?) was the real PITA that made the whole thing very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I have not made many modules, but I think you need to 'provide' the functions that you want to  load into the new namespace.

```
(module pyscheme scheme
  (provide
   link-python
   Py_Initialize
   <...>)
  (require foreign)
  (unsafe!)

  (define (link-python [lib "/usr/lib/libpython2.6.so"])
    (ffi-lib lib)))
(require pyscheme)
(link-python "/weird/location/for/libpython.so")
(Py_Initialize)
```

Answer (score 0):

CMake can automatically find `libpython` path:

`find_package( PythonLibs 3.3 REQUIRED )`

More detailed example [here](https://github.com/niitsuma/pyjsonrpcembd/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt).

Then you can use some linked sherd lib.
For example:
https://github.com/niitsuma/pyjsonrpcembd